# Laravel Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I have a connection to a SQL Server database and I have a model route binding setup for an event. Like so:

```
public function show(Event $event)
{

}
```

When event is a valid id I get the event and load it. When the ID is not valid I show a 404 page. When I enter something crazy like a string 'woifwornfroein' I get an error:

> SQLSTATE[22018]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value
>   'tnkrnbktrnj' to data type int. (SQL: select top 1 * from [events]
>   where [id] = tnkrnbktrnj and [events].[deleted_at] is null)

Obviously because it's expecting an int and the user is passing a string. How can I prevent this?

I tried casting it to an `(int)` in the `getIdAttribute` but that didn't do anything.

Comment: Seems pretty clear; `'tnkrnbktrnj'` definately isn't an `int`.

Comment: Test whether its actually an int in code before querying the database?

Comment: I suppose it's clear that `id` is an int column & `tnkrnbktrnj` isn't an int

Comment: [Laravel 6.x Docs - Routing - Route Parameters - Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints)